# How do I move an existing image without Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, move

I created multiple images without the use of interface builder. I used this code:

```
for (Row* row in parser.rows) {
        CGRect IphoneFrameImageRect;
        IphoneFrameImageRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 150.0f, 150.0f);
        UIImageView *IphoneFrame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:IphoneFrameImageRect];
        NSString *IphoneFrameurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://some.url.com/iphone/IphoneFrame.png"];
        [IphoneFrame setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:IphoneFrameurl]]]];
        [IphoneFrame setTag:(i)];
        IphoneFrame.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance

        [self.view addSubview:IphoneFrame];
        [IphoneFrame release];
}
```

I need to move these images to a different location in landscape mode. I did tag each image and it looks I can select the images back using this tag. But how can I gave the image a new coordinate ? I have this code:

```
-(void)positionViews {
    UIInterfaceOrientation destOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

    int i=4; //Picture with tag=4 for example
    UIImage *tempImage=(UIImage *)[self.view viewWithTag:(i)];

    // HOW TO MOVE ??

}
```

I am able to do this with a button using this code:

```
UIButton *tempButton=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
[temp setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, X10ButtonWidth, X10ButtonHeight)];
```

Comment: Shouldn't tempImage be a UIImageView? If you change it to UIImageView you should be able to call setFrame like you did with the Button.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different things / classes :

- `UIImage` that represent image **data**, with its pixels, in memory
- `UIImageView` that represent a view to **display** an image onscreen.

If it's more clear to you, an `UIImage` is to `UIImageView` what `NSString` is for an `UILabel`. The object representing the data/content is different from the view that can display it on screen.

So when you want to retrieve your imageview using the tag you set, you retrieve a **view**, especially an `UIImageView` for what matters, not an `UIImage`.

---

Change your cast to `UIImageView` and you will be able to call `setFrame:` on it the same way you do for your `UIButton` (as `setFrame:` is a method of the `UIView` class, and both `UIImageView` and `UIButton` are subclasses of `UIView`).

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:(i)];
[tempImageView setFrame:...];
```

Or don't even do any cast, as `viewWithTag:` returns a `UIView` and that's all you need if you just want to change the frame: whether it's a basic `UIView` or specifically a `UIImageView` or whatever kind of view does not matter if you just want to change the `frame` property, as this is a property of the generic `UIView` class and can be applied to any `UIView`, whatever specific subclass of `UIView` it is.

```
UIView *tempImageView = [self.view viewWithTag:(i)];
[tempImageView setFrame:...];
```